# Why the function IndexOf returns -1 from ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, indexof

Why does the function `IndexOf()` return -1 from a combobox? When I debug, the combobox has 7 items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < KontynentComboBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if((napis5.ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString()) ==  ((((DataRowView)KontynentComboBox2.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString())))
   {
      int inc = KontynentComboBox2.Items.IndexOf((((DataRowView)KontynentComboBox2.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString()));
      KontynentComboBox2.SelectedIndex = inc;
   }
}
```

Comment: It couldn't find the item you're looking for.

Comment: just set the selected index to `i` rather than trying to find the index of the current item.  You already know the index.

Comment: Do you have enough casting in your `for` loop?  :)

Comment: Servy I knew that when I wrote something loops :)
thanks for the hint of fatigue probably did not notice.                Do not know why IndexOf not working for ComboBox?

Comment: @user231605 Because the item that you're looking for isn't in the collection, which is the case because you're not looking for an item, but rather one value within that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1 is a common return value to mean nothing was found.  For searching functions that return the index of what it is searching for, -1 means the item isn't in the list.

The likely reason is that IndexOf is expecting an object.  The string you are searching for is  likely a property of the object, not the object itself so IndexOf is comparing some object to a string and they don't match.

Instead of SelectedIndex try SelectedValue.  As long as the value property of the combo box holds the strings you want, then .NET will search the items in the combo box to find the one whose value matches the given parameter.

```
KontynentComboBox2.SelectedValue =(((DataRowView)KontynentComboBox2.Items[i]).Row.ItemArray[0].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that The `IndexOf()` is looking for a `string` while you combobox has 7 non string Items .so he couldn't find its index. Try to fill yo combo with items of type `string` instead of doing it in XAML if it's the case.